# How do I get or print the raw sql query from a model query

Tags: php, lithium

I have a sample model query to read all the posts from the table as shown below

```
$posts = Posts::find('all');
```

Any function/method available in li3, that could print the above query into a plain sql query as shown below

```
select * from Posts;
```

Comment: [The Docs](https://li3.me/docs/book/manual/1.x/common-tasks/filters#applying-filters-logging)